# How to Validate method on button click

Tags: java, android

In ***ComparingValues();*** method, i have compared value for TextViews, but now i need to validate my method using button click....

I want if ***all three matches found*** on **ComparingValues();** *method*, then need to call:-

```
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

else

```
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**View my code:**

```
    btnLicenseCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLicenseCheck);
    btnLicenseCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // if all 3 matches found then need to show
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // else
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            LicenseValidation();                                

        }
    });               
}

public void ComparingValues()
{

        editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        strPassword = editPassword.getText().toString();

        /*** comparing password ***/
        if(strPassword.equals(textPassword))
        {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Match !",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          editPassword.setText(null);
        }
        else 
        {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Does not match !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        /*** comparing deviceID ***/
        if(strDeviceID.equals(textDeviceID))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DeviceID Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DeviceID Does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        /*** comparing emailID ***/
        if(strEmailID.equals(textEmailID))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EmailID Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EmailID Does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem now?

Comment: So have you got any error??

Comment: yeah   
 
but to show status for every match i am also showing ComparingValues(); method inside onClick(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside onclick do this

```
if(strPassword.equals(textPassword)&&strDeviceID.equals(textDeviceID) && strEmailID.equals(textEmailID))
{

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: but to show status for every match i am also showing ComparingValues(); method inside onClick(...)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
    if(strPassword.equals(textPassword) && strDeviceID.equals(textDeviceID) && strEmailID.equals(textEmailID))

    {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    editPassword.setText(null);
    }
    else if(!strPassword.equals(textPassword))
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Does not match !",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else if(!strDeviceID.equals(textDeviceID))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DeviceID Does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(strEmailID.equals(textEmailID))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EmailID Does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
else{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```